# In QGIS how do I represent a polygon with no data as grey, and those with a value of zero as white?

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, vector

Imagine I'm coloring the below polygons in on a map. I want to represent the values using graduated symbology, with the highest value the darkest red and the zero value white. However, I want to express the #N/A value as grey.

[image: Take for example this spreadsheet.]

Comment: Duplicate the layer.  In the duplicate use a definition query to limit it to #N/A.  Symbolize that as gray.  In the original use a definition query to exclude #N/A.  Then apply graduated symbology to that layer.

Comment: In the graded categorie, you can add this formula CASE WHEN "CE" IS NOT NULL THEN "CE" ELSE -100 END, so that it will transform the NULL into -100. Use the color ramp you want and just select grey for the -100 value.

Answer (score 2):

Apply your graduated symbology, then change your symbology type to Rule-based (the rules will default to the existing graduated symbology, but you can tweak each class if you need after changing), then add a new rule and set it to "Else" instead of "Filter".

[image]